# Addressable URL Forms with Search Parameters?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on a "staging" system where information about individuals comes in (separate database) and the staff will process the data to research whether the contact already exists. I trying to figure out whether it's possible to create addressable URLs into our Dynamics 2011 CRM system that populate with search parameters from the data in staging application. Basically, I want to give staff the quickest possible way to search contacts based on the last name (example) of the contact in the staging database (custom application). I want to program a link that says "search for this last name in CRM" and have it open a new CRM application window. (All staff will be in IE and on the local network).

Is this possible? I know I can open entities by passing a guid as a parameter, but in this case the guid is not known. This is to aid in researching the contact to see whether it exists.

Thanks

Comment: What is your staging system?  I'm just trying to figure out how the user is going to know they have a person to search for...

Comment: It's a totally independent custom application. Doesn't touch CRM at all. Essentially, they'll access an interface that shows all "records" that haven't been qualified yet (haven't been flagged for exists in CRM). What I am looking for is a fast way to take the information on this page (first name, last name, etc.) and open a new CRM window that automatically loads a search contact view with those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With this being an independent application that doesn't exist inside CRM, you probably want to look at the SDK and read the records inside CRM.

Another option would be to have your independent application inside CRM.  You could use JavaScript to search/open the records.

If you want to go the route you are talking, you can (somewhat).  You'd use an iFrame and the PostMessage feature to pass back and forth messages to the 2011 form.  You'll have to create a receiving handler inside of the CRM form and change the scope to the parent.  Seems tedious.

I'd just opt for treating CRM as a database backend and read/write what you need via the SDK.